# Шаблон проектирования Фабрика

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Может ли данный пример служить примером реализации паттерна `FactoryMethod` или он есть ошибочных по отношению именно к этому паттерну?

```
public class RentCar {
    public static Car getRentCar(Object object) {
        Car car = null;
        if (object instanceof BmwCar) {
            car = new BmwCar();
        } else if (object instanceof PejouCar) {
            car = new PejouCar();
        }
        return car;
    }
}
```

Класс:

```
public abstract class Car {
    public abstract int getMaxSpeed();
    public abstract String getMark();
}
```

Импл:

```java
public class BmwCar extends Car {

    @Override
    public int getMaxSpeed() {
        return 120;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMark() {
        return "BMW";
      }
    }

    public class PejouCar extends Car {
    
    @Override
    public int getMaxSpeed() {
        return 80;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMark() {
        return "Pejou";
    }
}
```

Comment: То, что вы привели -- это не Factory Method, а Abstract Factory.

Comment: @andreycha насколько я знаю, для абстрактной фабрики, должна быть еще и абстракция конкретной фабрики и ее имплементиция, так как фабрика создает целое семейство объектов, но в этом случае есть только один метод, который создает один объект наследник. 
не думаю, что это фабрика. но и не могу понять или это правильный фабричный метод.

Comment: Да, попутал. Все верно говорите. А по поводу корректности вам ниже правильно ответили.

Answer (score 3):

Странный получается фэктори метод - в текущей реализации для того, чтобы получить, например, экземпляр класса BmwCar, вы должны передать в метод getRentCar.... экземпляр класса BmwCar! В этом нет смысла. Так было бы лучше:

```
public static Car getRentCar(String carName) {
    Car car = null;
 if ("BMW".equals(carName)) {
    car = new BmwCar();
} else if ("Peugeot".equals(carName)) {
    car = new PeugeotCar();
}
return car; }
```

**Апдейт** после обсуждения в комментах:
С чисто формальной точки зрения, реализация является верной, т.к. явным образом не указывается, экземпляр какого именно класса должен вернуться из метода

Comment: как я понимаю, изменения передачи параметром не изменяет логики инициализации объектов. именно в этом случае, я не до конца понимаю или этот подход вообще правильный.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern: "In class-based programming, the factory method pattern is a creational pattern that uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that will be created." У вас, на мой взгляд, нарушено важное условие - вы целенаправленно сообщаете методу, инстансы какого именно класса создавать, передавая инстансы именно того класса, которые хотите получить обратно.

Comment: вы помоему не правильно понимаете значение "without having to specify the exact class". Это значит, что не можно использовать не instanceof, а что инициализация класса, должна просходить без явного указания самого класса. 
Пример: 
BmwCar car = new BmwCar(); 

В моем случае, этого не происходит.

Comment: Мм.. Пожалуй, соглашусь. Но не потому, что "нельзя использовать instanceof" - я этого не говорил. А просто потому, что, например, у BmwCar может быть наследник OtherBmwCar, для которого object instanceof BmwCar вернёт true и вы получите на выходе BmwCar... В общем, хоть и кривая, но чисто формально правильная реализация.

Answer (score 1):

```java
// Производители машин
public enum CarManufacturer
{
    BMW,
    Mercedes
}

// Фабрика
public class CarFactory
{
    public static Car makeCar(CarManufacturer type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case CarManufacturer.BMW:
                return new BMW();
            case CarManufacturer.Mercedes:
                return new Mercedes();
            default:
                return new Lada();
        }
    }
}
```